# Extracting base change using perl script

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I need some help with this perl script as I am an absolute beginner of perl. I have my code below which gives me mismatch at specific position from bowtie.out for the  given sequence ($sequence) length (here I am searching within sequence of length 22). ARGV[0] is the `bowtie.out` file and ARGV[1] is the maximum sequence length. 
This gives me the number of letters or base change (such as, A>T) at specific position for each change type. However, I also want to $position_ref for each change type and get the result as shown below. What do I need to do to this code to get the result as shown below?
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
# usage ./script.pl bowtie.out 22 

my $sread = "ACGT-read";
my $strand ="-";
my $name = "bill";
my $position = 1;
my $sequence = "ACGT";
my $quality = "good";
my $d2 = "d2";
my $d3 = "d3";
my $class= $ARGV[1];
my @mray;
my @lines;
my $min = 10;

for (my $i=0; $i < $class; $i++) {
    $mray[$i][0]=0;
    $mray[$i][1]=0;
    $mray[$i][2]=0;
    $mray[$i][3]=0;
    $mray[$i][4]=0;
    $mray[$i][5]=0;
    $mray[$i][6]=0;
    $mray[$i][7]=0;
    $mray[$i][8]=0;
    $mray[$i][9]=0;
    $mray[$i][10]=0;
    $mray[$i][11]=0;
}

open (INFILE, "<$ARGV[0]") || die "couldn't open the 1 infile!";

while ($rln = <INFILE>){
    chomp $rln;
    ($sread, $strand, $name, $position, $sequence, $quality, $d2,$d3) = split("\t",$rln);
#   print "what is d3 \n $d3\n";
    $seq_len = length ($sequence);
    if ($seq_len == $class && $d3){
        $position_ref = $position; 
# This is where I need help. I want to paste these values (from $position_ref) to the corresponding columns as shown in the result below.
        print "what is position_ref \n $position_ref\n";
#   print "what is d3 \n $d3\n";
       ($position, $d2) = split(":",$d3);
#   print "what is d2 \n $d2\n";
       $var = substr $d2, -1;
       $var2 = substr $d2, 0;

       if ($var2 eq "A>T" ) { $mray[$position][0]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "A>G" ) { $mray[$position][1]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "A>C" ) { $mray[$position][2]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "C>T" ) { $mray[$position][3]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "C>G" ) { $mray[$position][4]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "C>A" ) { $mray[$position][5]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "G>T" ) { $mray[$position][6]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "G>A" ) { $mray[$position][7]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "G>C" ) { $mray[$position][8]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "T>A" ) { $mray[$position][9]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "T>G" ) { $mray[$position][10]++ }
       if ($var2 eq "T>C" ) { $mray[$position][11]++ }


#   print "what is mray \n $mray[$position][3]\n";
       if ($position == ($class-1)) {
           $read = substr $sequence, 0, $class-1;
           push (@lines, $read);
#   print "what is read \n $read\n";
#   print "what is position \n $position\n";
       }
    }
}
close (INFILE);
print "Pos\tA>T\tA>G\tA>C\tC>T\tC>G\tC>A\tG>T\tG>A\tG>C\tT>A\tT>G\tT>C\n";
for (my $i=0; $i < $class; $i++) {
    $pnum = $i + 1;
    print "$pnum\t$mray[$i][0]\t$mray[$i][1]\t$mray[$i][2]\t$mray[$i][3]\t$mray[$i][4]\t$mray[$i][5]\t$mray[$i][6]\t$mray[$i][7]\t$mray[$i][8]\t$mray[$i][9]\t$mray[$i][10]\t$mray[$i][11]\n";
}

@lines = sort(@lines); # sort the list
$count = 0;
foreach my $line(@lines) # loop thru list
 {
    if ($line eq $oldline)
        {
          $count++;
        }  
        else 
        { 
          if ($count >= $min) {print "$oldline\t$count\n";}
#          print "$count\n";
          $count=1;
          $oldline=$line;
        }
 }

exit;
```

bowtie.out

```
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:9668:1894 1:N:0:TAATCG  -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 12006   TCACCAGGAAGATAAAACACGA  JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA  0   12:T>A
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:3363:1894 1:N:0:TAATCG  -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 1108    GCACCAGGAAGATAAAACACGT  JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA  0   12:T>A
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:8521:1912 1:N:0:TAATCG  -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 13807   CACACAAATCATGGACGAAGATGA    JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA    0   23:G>C
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:11343:1912 1:N:0:TAATCG -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 11823   TTTACAATCGTTTGCAGTCTATCA    JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA    0   
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:17056:1930 1:N:0:TAATCG +   reverseKF898354_1_14561 1970    TGCGCAGGACAAGAACTGAATG  AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ  0   19:C>A
    K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:11515:1965 1:N:0:TAATCG -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 9030    TGTCTGAAAATAACACGTCCAA  JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA  0   5:A>G
```

Result I am getting:

```
Pos A>T A>G A>C C>T C>G C>A G>T G>A G>C T>A T>G T>C
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0
14  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
21  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

result I want (tab delimited):

```
Pos A>T position_ref    A>G position_ref    A>C position_ref    C>T position_ref    C>G position_ref    C>A position_ref    G>T position_ref    G>A position_ref    G>C position_ref    T>A position_ref    T>G position_ref    T>C position_ref
1   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
2   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
3   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
4   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
5   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
6   0       1   9030    0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
7   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
8   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
9   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
10  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
11  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
12  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
13  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       2   12006   1108        0   
14  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
15  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
16  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
17  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
18  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
19  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
20  0       0       0       0       0       1   11823   0       0       0       0               0   
21  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0   
22  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0
```

Comment: What are the values in `@ARGV` when you run your program? I'm guessing they're "22" and "bowtie.out", but I'd rather not waste my time guessing. Also, is the result you show the actual result or the result you want to get? It's really helpful if you show us both and describe in detail what the difference is.

Comment: @DaveCross Argv is the maximum length of sequence. If the sequence is longer than argv, I 
want to skip those rows. If you run the code, you will get everything but the position_ref columns. So I want to have position_ref column as well in my results (I want result just like what I have in the question).

Comment: You will need to restructure your program logic a bit. Currently the program keeps all data in the `@mray` array. You will need to add another column to store `$position_ref` in that array as well. Then you can output that value as well. Maybe consider using [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) for columnar input and output.

Comment: @Corion I would really appreciate if you could help with the code. I am an R person but find it difficult to work around in R.  I am  obviously struggling with perl even more.

Comment: You will have to look elsewhere for somebody to do your programming work. This site is about answering concrete questions, not a code writing service.

Comment: @MAPK: That doesn't really answer my question. You use two values from `@ARGV` - `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`. So saying "Argv is the maximum length of sequence" isn't really helpful. I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54285931/edit) to add a) definitions of the contents of `@ARGV` and b) details of the output you're expecting and exactly how that differs from what you're getting. Remember, the people who want to help you probably know very little about Bioinformatics. What is obvious to you probably isn't obvious to them.

Comment: @DaveCross ARGV[0] is the bowtie.out file (input file) and ARGV[1] is the maximum sequence length. Please see my updated question. Thank you!

Comment: My advice is to import into R as a tab-limited CSV and read it into a data frame. This is your natural forte. The code is pretty clunky, there are arrays where hashes are better and complex arrays where simple loops would be preferable, eg. my @array = qw(A G C T); then loop the combinations excluding identical nucleotides

Answer (score 1):

Your code splits your input data on tab characters. But your sample file doesn't contain tab characters (because tabs are lost when you copy and paste to a web page). I tried converting all runs of whitespace to tabs, and now I think there's a mismatch between the input data and the variables that you split it into.

For example, the first line of data looks like this:

```
K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:9668:1894 1:N:0:TAATCG  -   reverseKF898354_1_14561 12006   TCACCAGGAAGATAAAACACGA  JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA  0   12:T>A
```

If we assume that all the whitespace is actually a tab, then we end up with the following variables:

- `$sread`: K00363:128:HV3CJBBXX:3:1101:9668:1894 1:N:0:TAATCG
- `$strand`: -
- `$name`: reverseKF898354_1_14561
- `$position`: 12006
- `$sequence`: TCACCAGGAAGATAAAACACGA
- `$quality`: JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFFFAA
- `$d2`: 0
- `$d3`: 12:T>A

I think that's wrong. I think a lot of this is one column out. I suspect the problem is the third column - the one that contains `+` or `-`. Either it's not supposed to be a separate column, or it needs its own variable.

If I add a new variable to the `split()` call to store the `+`/`-`, then your code actually does something. But it's still not the output that you say you're expecting and I don't know enough about your data to work out what the next step is.

Comment: @MAPK: So what you are saying is that the first two columns in your input file should be combined as one. Ok. Is that first whitespace column a space character or a tab?

Comment: That should be whitespace. Yes those two should be combined as one.

Comment: "Whitespace" is not a precise term to use. Both spaces and tabs are whitespace. Is it a space or is it a tab? Note: I'm not asking what it should be, I'm asking what it actually is in your copy of the input file.

Comment: In my file, it is space and actual columns are separated by tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your desired output, you need the reference position rather than the count of a particular base change: try substituting in your script "++" in hashes with "$position_ref" as follows:

```
# usage ./script.pl bowtie.out 22 

my $sread = "ACGT-read";
my $strand ="-";
my $name = "bill";
my $position = 1;
my $sequence = "ACGT";
my $quality = "good";
my $d2 = "d2";
my $d3 = "d3";
my $class= $ARGV[1];
my @mray;
my @lines;
my $min = 10;

for (my $i=0; $i < $class; $i++) {
    $mray[$i][0]=0;
    $mray[$i][1]=0;
    $mray[$i][2]=0;
    $mray[$i][3]=0;
    $mray[$i][4]=0;
    $mray[$i][5]=0;
    $mray[$i][6]=0;
    $mray[$i][7]=0;
    $mray[$i][8]=0;
    $mray[$i][9]=0;
    $mray[$i][10]=0;
    $mray[$i][11]=0;
}

open (INFILE, "<$ARGV[0]") || die "couldn't open the 1 infile!";

while ($rln = <INFILE>){
    chomp $rln;
    ($sread, $strand, $name, $position, $sequence, $quality, $d2,$d3) = split("\t",$rln);
#   print "what is d3 \n $d3\n";
    $seq_len = length ($sequence);
    if ($seq_len == $class && $d3){
        $position_ref = $position; 
# This is where I need help. I want to paste these values (from $position_ref) to the corresponding columns as shown in the result below.
        print "what is position_ref \n $position_ref\n";
#   print "what is d3 \n $d3\n";
       ($position, $d2) = split(":",$d3);
#   print "what is d2 \n $d2\n";
       $var = substr $d2, -1;
       $var2 = substr $d2, 0;

       if ($var2 eq "A>T" ) { $mray[$position][0]=$position_ref}
       if ($var2 eq "A>G" ) { $mray[$position][1]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "A>C" ) { $mray[$position][2]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "C>T" ) { $mray[$position][3]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "C>G" ) { $mray[$position][4]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "C>A" ) { $mray[$position][5]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "G>T" ) { $mray[$position][6]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "G>A" ) { $mray[$position][7]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "G>C" ) { $mray[$position][8]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "T>A" ) { $mray[$position][9]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "T>G" ) { $mray[$position][10]=$position_ref }
       if ($var2 eq "T>C" ) { $mray[$position][11]=$position_ref}


#   print "what is mray \n $mray[$position][3]\n";
       if ($position == ($class-1)) {
           $read = substr $sequence, 0, $class-1;
           push (@lines, $read);
#   print "what is read \n $read\n";
#   print "what is position \n $position\n";
       }
    }
}
close (INFILE);
print "Pos\tA>T\tA>G\tA>C\tC>T\tC>G\tC>A\tG>T\tG>A\tG>C\tT>A\tT>G\tT>C\n";
for (my $i=0; $i < $class; $i++) {
    $pnum = $i + 1;
    print "$pnum\t$mray[$i][0]\t$mray[$i][1]\t$mray[$i][2]\t$mray[$i][3]\t$mray[$i][4]\t$mray[$i][5]\t$mray[$i][6]\t$mray[$i][7]\t$mray[$i][8]\t$mray[$i][9]\t$mray[$i][10]\t$mray[$i][11]\n";
}

@lines = sort(@lines); # sort the list
$count = 0;
foreach my $line(@lines) # loop thru list
 {
    if ($line eq $oldline)
        {
          $count++;
        }  
        else 
        { 
          if ($count >= $min) {print "$oldline\t$count\n";}
#          print "$count\n";
          $count=1;
          $oldline=$line;
        }
 }
exit;
```